# Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter Error in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

Creating a simple card game (Set) and I have a function in the model that deals X cards onto the deck. Currently, when I click the deal card button they all show up at once so I added the timer so that they would appear one after another. This gives the error "Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter" Any ideas on what I can fix?

```
mutating func deal(_ numberOfCards: Int) {
        for i in 0..<numberOfCards {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.3 * Double(i), repeats: false) { _ in
                if deck.count > 0 {
                    dealtCards.append(deck.removeFirst())
                }
            }
        }    
}
```

Comment: You should use a timer only when updating the UI. Do your shuffle/dealing and once you finish that call a method that only updates the UI

Comment: I would use a UIView animation instead of a timer

Comment: "so that they would appear one after another" That's the view's job, not the model's. The model should stay the same. Move the timer code to your view.

Comment: @Sweeper that's what I was trying to do but the only way I found to do that would be to have the View do the ForLoop which creates problems later in the code. Would there be a way to have the deal function in model add all X cards to the array then the view add each one one by one?

Comment: @LeoDabus if the dealing and shuffling is done by adding cards to an array in the model how do I make them all animate individually. Except by calling dealcard 12 form the view.

Answer (score 1):

A timer is not even required. You can use transitions in combination with an animation to get the desired effect. Here the transition is delayed based on the index of the card:

```
class CardModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var cards: [Int] = []
    
    func deal(_ numberOfCards: Int) {
        cards += (cards.count ..< (cards.count + numberOfCards)).map { $0 }
    }
    
    func clear() {
        cards = []
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var cardModel = CardModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0 ..< self.cardModel.cards.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        CardView(cardNumber: self.cardModel.cards[index])
                            .transition(.offset(x: geometry.size.width))
                            .animation(Animation.easeOut.delay(Double(index) * 0.1))
                    }
                }
                
                Button(action: { self.cardModel.deal(2) }) {
                    Text("Deal")
                }
                
                Button(action: { self.cardModel.clear() }) {
                    Text("Clear")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    let cardNumber: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            .frame(width: 9, height: 16)
    }
}
```

Or a bit simpler (without the CardModel):

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var cards: [Int] = []
    
    func deal(_ numberOfCards: Int) {
        cards += (cards.count ..< (cards.count + numberOfCards)).map { $0 }
    }
    
    func clear() {
        cards = []
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0 ..< self.cards.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        CardView(cardNumber: self.cards[index])
                            .transition(.offset(x: geometry.size.width))
                            .animation(Animation.easeOut.delay(Double(index) * 0.1))
                    }
                }
                
                Button(action: { self.deal(2) }) {
                    Text("Deal")
                }
                
                Button(action: { self.clear() }) {
                    Text("Clear")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    let cardNumber: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            .frame(width: 9, height: 16)
    }
}
```

**Note** this approach works fine if you're centering the cards, because the previous cards will need to shift too. If you left-align the cards however (using a spacer) the animation delay will be present for the cards that do not need to shift (the animation starts with an awkward delay). If you need to account for this case, you'll need to make the newly inserted index part of the model.

Comment: This is a bit different than the original code. The original `deal(_:)` allows you to add cards to an existing hand. This version always replaces the hand with a completely new hand of a given size. If I'm reading it correctly, I don't think this animation approach will work if you switch to `append` rather than replacing.

Comment: @RobNapier Good catch. I just tried: it **kind of** works with appending, but I'm not sure if the effect is what the OP intended.

Comment: @RobNapier I agree the identifiable struct is a better approach in a ForEach loop, but i still need the index to calculate the animation delay.

Comment: (last comment wasn't needed, the `id` parameter handles it)

Answer (score 0):

(This may be duplicating what Jack Goossen has written; go look there first, and if it's not clear, this may give some more explanation.)

The core problem here is that you appear to be treating a struct as a reference type. A struct is a value. That means that each holder of it has its own copy. If you pass a value to a Timer, then the Timer is mutating its own copy of that value, which can't be `self`.

In SwiftUI, models are typically reference types (classes). They represent an identifiable "thing" that can be observed and changes over time. Changing this type to a class would likely address your problem. (See Jack Goossen's answer, which uses a class to hold the cards.)

This is backwards of the direction that Swift had been moving in with UIKit, where views were reference types and the model was encouraged to be made of value types. In SwiftUI, views are structs, and the model is usually made of classes.

(Using Combine with SwiftUI, it's possible to make both view and model into value types, but that's possibly beyond what you were trying to do here, and is a bit more complex if you haven't studied Combine or reactive programming already.)

Comment: Very insightful. Just to nitpick: you can use the animation approach in the ForEach loop with value types as well, as long as they are identifiable (the index in my answer). Using ObservedObject iso State was more of a habit than intentional choice.

Comment: The ForEach loop can be over value types, but the observed object must be a class (which is the thing that applies the `append`).